# C# WebApi 2 CORS not working When ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, angularjs, cors, asp.net-web-api2

i have done a token authentication based webapi in C#, my problem is when i need to validate the user into an SQL Server Database in another Server, everything works fine until i execute the reader against the connection, then it return error of CORS in the browser, when i remove the reader works fine and returns the token, but i need to validate with SQL Server, here is my code:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        string nombre = "";

        string cadenaConexion = "Data Source=ipSQLServer;Initial Catalog=EDELIVERY;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userDataBase;Password=PasswdUserDataBase";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "select *  from Usuario a inner join TipoUsuario b on a.CodTipoUsuario = b.Codigo where a.Usuario = '" + context.UserName + "' and a.Clave = '" + context.Password + "');";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                nombre = reader.GetString(0).ToString().Trim();
            }
        }

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        if (context.UserName == "admin" && context.Password == "admin")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Nombre Admin"));


            context.Validated(identity);

        }
        else if (context.UserName == "user" && context.Password == "user")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Nombre Usuario"));
            context.Validated(identity);

        }
        else {
            context.SetError("error_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code of the client side is in angularjs:

```
loginApi: function (infoLogin) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var url = "http://localhost:51372/token";                
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: 'username='+infoLogin.usuario+'&password='+infoLogin.passwd+'&grant_type=password'
            }).then(function (resp, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(resp);
            },
            function (err, status, headers, config) {                        
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });               

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

I made a simple database connection, just to retrieve some data, just for the example, thanks if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable CORS in your web api.

Try put this in your web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```